# Missing parameters in Rails Controller when using multipart/form-data in React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios, multipartform-data

I am using Rails and React with Axios to create a record. In my React app I collect all the data and put it inside of `FormData` like this:

```js
const createVtc = () => {

        let data = new FormData()

        data.append('image', vtcImageToSend)
        data.append('name', vtcName)
        data.append('description', vtcDescription)
        data.append('main_color', vtcColor)
        data.append('minimum_age_to_join', vtcMinimumAge)

        axios.post(`${ROOT_API}/v1/vtcs/create`, data, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            history.push('/dashboard')
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    };
```

This contains all the necessary data in order to create a record.

This is the Rails controller responsible for creating it:

```rb
def create
    vtc = Vtc.new(vtc_params)
    # other code is not important
  end
```

And this is `vtc_params` private function:

```rb
  def vtc_params
    params.require(:vtc).permit(:id, :name, :description, :minimum_age_to_join, :main_color, :image)
  end
```

Pretty standard stuff. It worked until I had to implement picture upload which made me switch to `FormData` upload and since then Rails throws this error:

```
 ActionController::ParameterMissing in V1::VtcsController#create 
 param is missing or the value is empty: vtc
```

I can assume what's the problem but I don't know how to fix it. Before `FormData` I used to send it like this:

```js
// other stuff
axios.post(`${ROOT_API}/v1/vtcs/create`, {
    "vtc": {
        "name": vtcName,
        // etc.
    }
}, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
// other stuff
```

All of the data was inside of `"vtc"` object but now it's just `data` variable. I tried adding `{"vtc": data}` as Axios data which not surprisingly didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your data variable in an object with the key `vtc`:

```
  axios.post(`${ROOT_API}/v1/vtcs/create`, {vtc: data}, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer but as I stated in the last paragraph of the post, I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I missed that. Will delete my answer in a minute.

Comment: No need! Maybe it's good. I just checked `Params` tab in network tools of Firefox and it says `{"vtc":{}}`

Comment: Maybe it's something wrong with `FormData`? Because it has empty params.

Comment: Yes, seems like the actual data is missing. If you console.log at every step, maybe you can find where the bug is.

Comment: There is data in `Params` if I just set `data` instead of `{vtc: data}` as post data.

Comment: Would it make sense if I convert it to JSON or something? Maybe the format is wrong.

Comment: I was thinking that too with JSON, but it doesn't say that in the axios documentation. Worth a try.
Also what happens if you set `data = {vtc: data } outside of the axios.post?

Comment: Same thing. Params are still empty.